# Improve performance of sliding puzzle solver

Tags: performance, haskell

as a practice exercise I decided to code a sliding puzzle solver (like 8-puzzle or 15-puzzle). Now, the solution is there and it is working but the problem I face now is the runtime. I would like to request some help with optimising the solution (if at all possible). I'm interested to see what steps one could take to improve performance of their Haskell program.

My implementation can be found here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/166d8a3323a3f96eab04

Sample input file:

```
4
5  4  3  8 
9  2  6  1 
0 13 14  7 
15 11 10 12
```

If you run it under the profiler you will see that the amount of data we generate is about 9Gb. And the "problematic" functions are `manhattan` and `boardDistance`. I'm currently clueless about how to tackle these functions to optimise them (if at all possible). Seeking for your help!

Reference of "problematic" pieces:

```
-- | Manhattan distance of a tile at vector index on a board with dimensions n x n
manhattan :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
manhattan tile n index = if tile == 0 then 0 else rowDistance + columnDistance
    where
        (row, column) = v2m n index -- convert vector index to matrix index
        rowDistance = abs (row - ((tile - 1) `div` n))
        columnDistance = abs (column - ((tile - 1) `mod` n))

-- | Manhattan distance of the entire board
boardDistance :: BoardDimension -> Board -> Int
boardDistance n currentBoard = sum $ map (\index -> manhattan (currentBoard ! index) n index) [0..n*n-1]
```

Comment: Quick suggestions: use `quotRem` instead of `div` and `mod` separately in `manhattan` and `v2m`. Use `Data.Vector.Unboxed` to represent your board, it is much more efficient for primitive data types like `Int`.

Comment: I ran your code (compiling with `-O2`) on randomly generated puzzles of variable sizes (from 3 to 50) and it all completes in less than a second. Profiling shows that nearly 100% of the time is being spent inside of `isSolvable.numberOfInversions`. The calls to `manhattan` are instant. When I turn off optimizations, I get the behavior you describe. Moral of the story: if you expect performance, use `-O2`.

Comment: I do use `-O2` flag when compiling to test before I start to profile. The thing is that the puzzle mentioned above is the one that takes a lot of time and resources. Maybe the rest run fast but as long as I have the counterexample (the puzzle in the initial post) I'm interested in optimising the solution. Running this board on my Macbook Pro takes 3.9seconds at the moment (I already switched to `quotRem` from `div` and `mod` which sped things a bit up)

Comment: @ksaveljev why are those functions problematic? what form of profiling did you do? tick profiling or heap profiling? do you generate 9G resident, or allocate 9G total?

Answer (score -2):

Looking at the type of solution this is, I suspect a lot of your performance loss is coming from the poor performance of free monads (`Maybe` is a free monad). This is a prime example of where the [codensity transformation](http://comonad.com/reader/2011/free-monads-for-less/) will be a win.  Alternatively, you could use a monad designed for combinatorial search such as [logict](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/logict).

Comment: Feedback about why this answer is unhelpful?

Comment: While Maybe is the free monad corresponding to the `Const ()` functor, I don't see any indication that free monads are causing the issue here.  But, I also didn't downvote you.

Comment: I admit it was a hunch. I saw a branching recursive function on a free monad and my alarm went off.

Comment: No idea why there are downvotes. I'm unfamiliar with the concepts you have suggested (neither logict nor codensity transformation) but will try to learn about them! Thank you for the suggestion